# Mura CMS 7 - Getting publish date of page from iterator?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I have a local index that is pointing to a calendar, and grabbing the 4 most recent calendar entries. I have an iterator iterating over each of these items and outputting them via some custom markup. I can easily grab the title of the current item using:

```
#item.getTitle()#
```

But I'm unsure of how to grab the publish date that was set on the item. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: When in doubt with situations like this use the `getAllValues()` method to see what is available for you. You should be able to dump the results of that call and see what is available - `<cfdump var="#item.getAllValues()#">`

Answer (score 0):

There a few dates that you can access.

```
// this would need to be explicitly set when editing the content node
item.get('releaseDate');

// This is when the first version was initially created
item.get('created');

// This is slightly mis-labelled.  It's when this actually version was saved
item.get('lastUpdate');
```